# Why aren't parented object transformations backwards compatible in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I created some new characters for my animation recently. I modelled them on Blender 2.79 and copied them to 2.8. For the characters' eyelids, I have them applied to Lattice modifiers, and the eyelids and lattices are both parented to the characters using vertex (triangle). My problem is that with one character, in the original blender, the eyelids rotated around different axes normally, but in 2.8 they are messed up, and the rotations and locations are a lot more random and constrained. Some of the other characters' eyelids work fine in the new version, so is it just a bug?.

- 2.79 Blender, as you can see the eyelid rotates up and down normally
  [image]

-2.8 blender, rotating on a similar axis but with different results
[image]

Comment: I've tried to replicate your problem, but to me everything works fine. Could you please share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idcHmVaWnvK_Y4MTI2FLnB5-izYInbbN/view?usp=sharing - The first file, open this with 2.79
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vzGRy0OadGFIHQXFCZU5hvUtNMfh0qyl/view?usp=sharing - the one with the bugs, open with 2.8. 
Also I noticed that for some characters, the eyelids rotate normally, but for others, such as the dark blue spherical guy, one or both have glitched axes. do not.